# How to create a border around an NSImage CIFilter ObjC

Tags: objective-c, macos, border, nsimage, cifilter

I'm trying to create a stoke border around a PNG with transparent background in an **NSImage**.

I originally tried duplicating the image and having a larger scale and then using **CIFilter** to make it white - this works great for shapes like circles and other solid shapes.

However i'll have shapes like the example image below:

[image: Tree Image]

With this Image it doesn't work well at all.

I'm thinking that maybe I can do something with CIEdge and `CIMorphologyMaximum` but i'm not sure if i'm thinking in a good direction - would appreciate some advise if anyone has come across a similar challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `CIMorphologyMaximum` should be the way to go. Try this:

```
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

let ciImage = ...

// Apply morphology maximum to "erode" image in all direction into transparent area.
let filter = CIFilter.morphologyMaximum()
filter.inputImage = ciImage
filter.radius = 5 // border radius
let eroded = filter.outputImage!

// Turn all pixels of eroded image into desired border color.
let colorized = CIBlendKernel.sourceAtop.apply(foreground: .white, background: eroded)!.cropped(to: eroded.extent)

// Blend original image over eroded, colorized image.
let imageWithBorder = ciImage.composited(over: colorized)
```

And in **Objective-C**:

```
CIImage* ciImage = ...;

// Apply morphology maximum to "erode" image in all direction into transparent area.
CIFilter* erodeFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMorphologyMaximum"];
[erodeFilter setValue:ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[erodeFilter setValue:@5 forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];
CIImage* eroded = erodeFilter.outputImage;

// Turn all pixels of eroded image into desired border color.
CIImage* colorized = [[CIBlendKernel.sourceAtop applyWithForeground:[CIImage whiteImage] background:eroded] imageByCroppingToRect:eroded.extent];

// Blend original image over eroded, colorized image.
CIImage* imageWithBorder = [ciImage imageByCompositingOverImage:colorized];
```

---

Keep in mind that the border will extend the image *in all directions* which might result in a negative `origin` in working space. For example, an image with `extent` [0, 0, 50, 50] will have an `extent` of [-5, -5, 60, 60] after applying a 5 pixel border.

To compensate for that, you need to specify the `extent` of the *resulting image* when as the rect when rendering the image:

```
[ciContext createCGImage:imageWithBorder fromRect:imageWithBorder.extent];
```

Alternatively, you can move the image's origin to [0, 0] again after applying the border. But the resulting will still be larger than the input image, so keep that in mind.

```
imageWithBorder = [imageWithBorder imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-ciImage.extent.origin.x, -ciImage.extent.origin.y)];
```

---

As for the border size: The `inputRadius` you set on the erosion filter is in pixels. That means that large images will get a smaller relative border compared to small images.

To compensate for that, you can calculate the border radius as a percentile of the image size. This should create a uniform look among differently sized images. For instance:

```
NSNumber* radius = @(MAX(ciImage.extent.size.width, ciImage.extent.size.height) * 0.05);
```

Comment: Perfect, glad to know my thought path is in the right direction, do you know how I would do this in Obj-C sorry not familiar with swift or it's syntaxes yet.

Comment: Sure, see edit.

Comment: Perfect thanks Frank - i'll have a play around with had a small play around so far and looks good.

Comment: https://imgur.com/JvWDx4G
https://imgur.com/a20YkAH
https://imgur.com/A8OGCGi

I have a couple of questions - i'm seeing many images the border is cutting off - do you know why that would be - also the border varies in size depending on the image uploaded would there be away to keep that more uniform?

Comment: @GeraldTheGerm I extended my answer to address your questions.

Comment: Thanks Frank, appreciate your time and help - i'm away from my Mac right now as soon as i'm back i'll have a tinker and digest and learn what you've told me.

Comment: Works absolutely perfectly, go one last question is there a simple way to convert an NSColor / CIColor to a CIImage for the border color?

Comment: Absolutely! You can simply initialize it with `[CIImage imageWithColor:ciColor]`.

Comment: Perfect I kinda got it working with filters but this is much less resource heavy as easier to manage - can I ask you how you learnt this - as i've learnt more from you then I have from Apple Documentation! Are there any resources you'd recommend me reading? One day I hope to be as epic as you :)

Comment: Well, through years of trial and error.  I use Apple's code documentation for the CI types the most, but the (outdated) Core Image Programming Guide is also good for learning the basics. I can also recommend the free "Core Image for Swift" by @FlexMonkey on Apple Books. Though it's for Swift, all concepts are 1:1 transferrable to Objective-C.

Comment: Perfect really appreciate all the help you've given me - will continue to play around with everything and learn CI is really powerful especially when you understand what it can do better!